# Rails landing page routing and devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

My website should works just like facebook.com.
If the user is logged and if it goes to "/" it should be rendered **home** controller. If it isn't logged it should be render **landing_page** controller

> **"/**" && **user_signed_in?**   --->  **home** controller
>
> **"/"** && **user_not_logged**   --->  **landing_page** controller

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
get "landing_page/index"

root 'home#index', :as => :home
```

How I could keep a "before_filter" in ApplicationControl that run in every controllers except "landing_page" controller?

**Update**

If I go to "/en/landing_page" it render landing_page controller correctly (logged out), but if I go to "/" it redirect me to "/users/sign_in"

```
class LandingPageController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticate_user!

end
```

Routes.rb

```
 root 'landing_page#index'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SOLVED!

**LandingPageController**

```
class LandingPageController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

end
```

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :check_auth

def check_auth
    unless user_signed_in?
        redirect_to :controller => :landing_page
    end
end
 end
```

**ApplicationController**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticate_user!

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
 root 'landing_page#index'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that no matter if your are logged in or not, it would always render the landing page if you try to access '/' ? Didn't you want to set the root to HomeController#index (or something else that would then check_auth)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could easily add a before filter to handle this action.

Like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743861/rails-3-authenticate-and-before-filter)

Comment: nope. It still redirect me to /users/sign_in if I go to "/". Question updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write confirm_logged_in function action in controller

before_filter :confirm_logged_in

In that function you can mention how you want to render pages based on logged in user

```
def confirm_logged_in<br>
  unless session[:user_id]
  flash[:notice] = 'Please log in.'
  redirect_to(:controller => 'access', :action => 'login')
  return false #halts the before_filter<

else
return true
  end
end
```